# Geoportal to harvest services hosted by Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, esri-geoportal-server

I am trying to set up Geoportal to harvest services hosted by Geoserver. I tried follow this instructions:

1. Open your Geoportal Server.
2. Go to the Administration tab Choose the 'Add' option
3. Choose 'Register resource on the network' and click Proceed
4. In the URL resource form, paste the OGC GetCapabilities URL (including all parameters)
5. Keep the options for allowing the resource to be found and for it to be synchronized at an interval
6. Choose the interval.
7. Select if you want to be notified of synchronization results.
8. Click Save.
9. In the Manage page, approve this newly registered resource.

Now I did the following in Geoserver:

1. Registered a ArcSDE shapefile in Geoserver that I can see in "Layer Preview" and I can get the common formats like OpenStreet map working for the layer.

But what is an OGC GetCapabilities URL??? Where do i declared and link it to the layer I registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when registering an individual WMS service in Geoportal Server, there won't be further items other than the service itself. This is different from registering a metadata catalog (like CSW) or an ArcGIS Server itself (which may have multiple services). In those cases there will be related items that all came from the same source.

I registered the ArcGIS Server gismap.ciat in our sandbox Geoportal and you can see the [result of Geoportal harvesting all services from this site](http://gptogc.esri.com/geoportal/rest/find/document?searchText=sys.siteuuid%3a%5C%7B6383C988-BC85-4633-89AF-1CA10F7B65E4%5C%7D&start=1&max=10&f=searchpage&dojo.preventCache=1379105657894).

Details on how I achieved this and how in general you [publish resources](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/How-to-Publish-Resources#wiki-Register_a_resource_on_the_network) to Geoportal are on the wiki at GitHub.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the reply. It really helped me. I have another question about the Geoportal Preview link. Please have a look if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

The getCapabilities request is how GeoServer (and other WMS) tell a client about thier available layers, formats etc. It is available from the front page of you GeoServer installation.

See http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getcapabilities for more details. (The GeoServer manual is a fount of useful information :-))

Comment: ok I used: http://newrmg.ilri.cgiar.org:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities  But then I click on synchronize and click on "Show documents acquired from this repository" and its empty!!!

Comment: That server URL doesn't work in a browser either, so its probably wrong. Try something like http://gismap.ciat.cgiar.org/ArcGISServer/services/IA/CBase/MapServer/WMSServer?request=getcapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.1.1

Comment: Hi, I tried with your URL but again "Show documents acquired from this repository" retrieve an empty list!!! I don't get any error in the logs